# AWS configure issue on windows cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cmd, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to access my **'s3'** bucket using *boto3*, getting the following error:

`ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

Although, I have provided all the access tokens.

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id1,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key1,
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token1
)
```

Looked up for how to set up the config files using **awscli** so that *boto3* directly takes it from there, but after installing awscli *(tried both windows installer and pip install awscli)* when I run
`aws configure` cmd doesn't ask for access tokens. Neither is the command working.

I have added *\site-packages\bin* and *\Amazon\AWSCLIV2* in path folder, still doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: Command Promt]

Comment: A Session Token is only used for **temporary credentials**, such as those provided by calls to `AssumeRole` or `GetSessionToken`. Why are you using such credentials? How were you given them? You _can_ put a session token in the `~/.aws/credentials` file by specifying `aws_session_token =` but this can only be done by editing the file (not via `aws configure`).

Comment: I'm aware that a Session Token is used for the ongoing session and may have to keep on changing it every time the session ends. I got access to AWS educate account through my university so thought of learning a bit about it. 
I did not find this location ` ~/.aws/credentials ` anywhere, doesn't `aws configure` create this file if not present?

Comment: Your AWS CLI doesn't seem to be working properly. I suggest downloading it from https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ (it is now version 2). You can then use `aws configure` to enter the Access Key and Secret Key, then edit the file to add the Session Token.

Comment: I have installed the latest version, and checked whether it was properly installed. Result is still the same.

Comment: Your `aws --version` and `aws configure` commands are not responding correctly, plus the output is saying that it is v1. It looks like there is a program with the path. Try running `aws` with a full-path to make sure it is running the correct version.

Comment: Woah, definitely did not see the version my cmd was giving me. 
Apparently, I had both versions of awscli which was causing the issue.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `pip install awscli` installs V1 and the issue was caused because of two different versions V1 & V2.
Problem was solved by simply removing the old version.
`pip uninstall awscli`

Thanks to [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `%PATH%` environment variable, and remove/amend the variable to use the new AWS CLI tools, and also check for any other environment variable relating to AWS CLI and amend these also, and then test.